# cannot extract some of the div tags with beautifulsoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to obtain daily weather from the website 'https://www.timeanddate.com/weather' for the desired region and date. But I can not reach following div class with below code. What should I do?

I've tried to extract using BeautifulSoup. The information I want to extract is inside of the 'temp' and 'wdesc' div classes (which are the degrees and weather situations like; 'passing  clouds' or so.) So I've tried following codes;

[image: Screenshot]

```py
import requests

url = 'https://www.timeanddate.com/weather/spain/salou/historic?month=1&year=2014'

result = requests.get(url, verify = False)
soup = BeautifulSoup(result.text, "html.parser")
w1 = soup.findAll('div', attrs ={'class':'temp'})
w2 = soup.findAll('div', attrs ={'class':'wdesc'})
```

I  expect to get the degrees of weather (13 / 11 °C) from the w1 and the situation of the weather from w2 (Scattered clouds.). But instead I get two empty lists from w1 and w2.

Comment: If i go to this website and view source. I cannot find a div with class wdesc anywhere.
Are you sure you are looking in the correct location ?

Comment: @Oddmar Dam When I open the 'inspect element' and click inspector to the 'passing clouds' text in the website it shows 'wdesc' class in a div.

Comment: Yes, i can see that in firefox web developer toolbar, but i'm not sure that is the same your getting if your just downloading the text in python. 
Could you, in python, just do a find text for wdesc in the result ?

Comment: Yes, you are right soup in the python and the inspect element are not the same. Aren't they suppose to be the same? If not, do you know how to obtain the inspect element? Otherwise, isn't it very hard to extract what you want?

Comment: ```
import requests

url = 'https://www.timeanddate.com/weather/spain/salou/historic?month=1&year=2014'

result = requests.get(url, verify = False)
print(result.text.find('wdesc'))
```
Result is -1, not found

Comment: Can you make a screenshot of what element you are looking for ?

https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135483/how-can-i-add-a-screen-shot-into-my-question

Comment: I have added @Oddmar Dam thank you very much!

Comment: @GulsahAyhan soup and inspect will be different because the site is dynamic, meaning the data is rendered after the fact. So you `requests` is pulling that html source code before it's rendered, hence you do not have that data to parse. The 3 options you have: 1) use a browser simulation like Selenium that will open the page, let it render, THEN you can use BS to parse the html source; 2) See if you can access that data directly through an API; 3) search through the `<script>` tags as sometimes the data will be in there

Comment: I see the problem. You are hovering over the image. The content you are getting there is dynamically loaded.

If you look further down the page, there is a table below with all the same data. I believe you can find your information there.

Comment: @GulsahAyhan, what exactly would are you trying to pull?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data is in script so one of the solution is using Selenium . If you dont install yet you can install it :

```
https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.35/
```

This is the code :

```
from  selenium import webdriver

driver_path = r'chromedriverpath'
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=driver_path)
browser.get("https://www.timeanddate.com/weather/spain/salou/historic?month=1&year=2014")
meta = browser.execute_script('return data')


my_json_string = meta['detail']

print my_json_string
```

OUTPUT :

> [{u'hlsh': u'1 Oca', u'templow': 4, u'temp': 14, u'hum': 77, u'hls': u'1 Oca \xc7ar', u'ts': u'06:00', u'wd': 30, u'wind': 5, u'hl': True, u'date': 1388556000000, u'icon': 2, u'ds': u'1 Ocak 2014 \xc7ar\u015famba, 06:00 \u2014 12:00', u'baro': 1019, u'desc': u'Passing clouds.'}, {u'templow': 11, u'temp': 15, u'hum': 72, u'ts': u'12:00', u'wd': 210, u'wind': 9, u'date': 1388577600000, u'desc': u'Passing clouds.', u'ds': u'1 Ocak 2014 \xc7ar\u015famba, 12:00 \u2014 18:00', u'baro': 1016, u'icon': 2}, {u'templow': 9, u'temp': 11, u'hum': 90, u'ts': u'18:00', u'wd': 0, u'wind': 5, u'date': 1388599200000, u'desc': u'Passing clouds.', u'ds': u'1 Ocak 2014 \xc7ar\u015famba, 18:00 \u2014 00:00', u'baro': 1015, u'icon': 14}, {u'hlsh': u'2 Oca', u'wd': 0, u'hum': 0, u'hls': u'2 Oca Per', u'ts': u'00:00', u'wind': 0, u'hl': True, u'date': 1388620800000, u'icon': 36, u'ds': u'2 Ocak 2014 Per\u015fembe, 00:00 \u2014 06:00', u'baro': 0, u'desc': u'No weather data available'}, {u'templow': 6, u'temp': 15, u'hum': 93, u'ts': u'06:00', u'wd': 0, u'wind': 6, u'date': 1388642400000, u'desc': u'Passing clouds.', u'ds': u'2 Ocak 2014 Per\u015fembe, 06:00 \u2014 12:00', u'baro': 1013, u'icon': 2}, {u'templow': 15, u'temp': 18, u'hum': 61, u'ts': u'12:00', u'wd': 0, u'wind': 7, u'date': 1388664000000, u'desc': u'Passing clouds.', u'ds': u'2 Ocak 2014 Per\u015fembe, 12:00 \u2014 18:00', u'baro': 1013, u'icon': 2}, {u'templow': 13, u'temp': 15, u'hum': 80, u'ts': u'18:00', u'wd': 0, u'wind': 4, u'date': 1388685600000, u'desc': u'Passing clouds.', u'ds': u'2 Ocak 2014 Per\u015fembe, 18:00 \u2014 00:00', u'baro': 1014, u'icon': 14}, {u'hlsh': u'3 Oca', u'wd': 0, u'hum': 0, u'hls': u'3 Oca Cum', u'ts': u'00:00', u'wind': 0, u'hl': True, u'date': 1388707200000, u'icon': 36, u'ds': u'3 Ocak 2014 Cuma, 00:00 \u2014 06:00', u'baro': 0, u'desc': u'No weather data available'}, {u'templow': 9, u'temp': 18, u'hum': 76, u'ts': u'06:00', u'wd': 0, u'wind': 6, u'date': 1388728800000, u'desc': u'Passing clouds.', u'ds': u'3 Ocak 2014 Cuma, 06:00 \u2014 12:00', u'baro': 1015, u'icon': 2}, {u'templow': 17, u'temp': 20, u'hum': 55, u'ts': u'12:00', u'wd': 290, u'wind': 11, u'date': 1388750400000, u'desc': u'Passing clouds.', u'ds': u'3 Ocak 2014 Cuma, 12:00 \u2014 18:00', u'baro': 1016, u'icon': 2}, .. UP TO END

When you reach these list you can parse it with json or something else.Using selenium is one of the option

Comment: Thank you! What am I suppose to write as 'chrome driver path'?

Comment: Its a path where you downloaded .I mean like C://Download//chromedriver.exe @GulsahAyhan

Comment: I am going to ask you one more question @OmerTekbiyik, how did you decide 'return data' while coding meta = browser.execute_script('return data'). I mean, with the different url's it does not work and I've just wondered how you find this 'return data' part?

Comment: When you see the source of the url , datas in in the script which variable name is ‘data’ . Meta is returning the script who variable name is ‘data’ . It can be change according to script’s variable name @GulsahAyhan

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to have a look at the table called wt-his instead.
It seems to have rows of all the values your looking for.

[image: Screenshot of table]

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the table (provided it's under `<table>` tags), it's much easier to use Pandas to pull that, than to use BeautifulSoup directly.

```
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://www.timeanddate.com/weather/spain/salou/historic?month=1&year=2014'
tables = pd.read_html(url)
df = tables[-1]
```

**Output:**

```
print (df.to_string())
                  Unnamed: 0_level_0                        Conditions                                                                                               Comfort                                                                                    Unnamed: 7_level_0                Unnamed: 8_level_0
                                Time                Unnamed: 1_level_1                              Temp                           Weather                              Wind                Unnamed: 5_level_1                          Humidity                         Barometer                        Visibility
0                  7:00 amWed, Jan 1                               NaN                             39 °F                            Clear.                             3 mph                                 ↑                               93%                         30.07 "Hg                             10 mi
1                            7:30 am                               NaN                             41 °F                            Clear.                             3 mph                                 ↑                               87%                         30.07 "Hg                             10 mi
2                            8:00 am                               NaN                             41 °F                   Passing clouds.                             5 mph                                 ↑                               87%                         30.07 "Hg                               NaN
3                            8:30 am                               NaN                             43 °F                   Passing clouds.                             6 mph                                 ↑                               81%                         30.07 "Hg                               NaN
4                            9:00 am                               NaN                             43 °F                   Passing clouds.                             2 mph                                 ↑                               87%                         30.07 "Hg                               NaN
5                            9:30 am                               NaN                             46 °F                   Passing clouds.                             5 mph                                 ↑                               76%                         30.07 "Hg                               NaN
6                           10:00 am                               NaN                             48 °F                   Passing clouds.                             3 mph                                 ↑                               76%                         30.09 "Hg                               NaN
7                           10:30 am                               NaN                             54 °F                   Passing clouds.                           No wind                                 ↑                               67%                         30.09 "Hg                               NaN
8                           11:00 am                               NaN                             55 °F                   Passing clouds.                           No wind                                 ↑                               63%                         30.09 "Hg                               NaN
9                           11:30 am                               NaN                             55 °F                   Passing clouds.                             3 mph                                 ↑                               63%                         30.09 "Hg                               NaN
10                          12:00 pm                               NaN                             57 °F                   Passing clouds.                             6 mph                                 ↑                               63%                         30.07 "Hg                               NaN
11                          12:30 pm                               NaN                             57 °F                   Passing clouds.                             8 mph                                 ↑                               67%                         30.07 "Hg                               NaN
12                           1:00 pm                               NaN                             59 °F                   Passing clouds.                             9 mph                                 ↑                               68%                         30.04 "Hg                               NaN
13                           2:00 pm                               NaN                             59 °F                   Passing clouds.                            10 mph                                 ↑                               68%                         30.01 "Hg                               NaN
14                           2:30 pm                               NaN                             59 °F                   Passing clouds.                             9 mph                                 ↑                               68%                         30.01 "Hg                               NaN
15                           3:00 pm                               NaN                             57 °F                   Passing clouds.                             7 mph                                 ↑                               67%                         30.01 "Hg                               NaN
16                           3:30 pm                               NaN                             57 °F                   Passing clouds.                             6 mph                                 ↑                               67%                         29.98 "Hg                               NaN
17                           4:00 pm                               NaN                             57 °F                   Passing clouds.                             3 mph                                 ↑                               72%                         30.01 "Hg                               NaN
18                           4:30 pm                               NaN                             55 °F                   Passing clouds.                             3 mph                                 ↑                               77%                         30.01 "Hg                               NaN
19                           5:00 pm                               NaN                             55 °F                   Passing clouds.                             1 mph                                 ↑                               77%                         29.98 "Hg                               NaN
20                           5:30 pm                               NaN                             54 °F                   Passing clouds.                           No wind                                 ↑                               82%                         30.01 "Hg                               NaN
21                           6:00 pm                               NaN                             52 °F                   Passing clouds.                             1 mph                                 ↑                               88%                         29.98 "Hg                               NaN
22                           6:30 pm                               NaN                             52 °F                   Passing clouds.                             1 mph                                 ↑                               88%                         29.98 "Hg                               NaN
23                           7:30 pm                               NaN                             50 °F                   Passing clouds.                             3 mph                                 ↑                               94%                         29.98 "Hg                               NaN
24                           8:00 pm                               NaN                             50 °F                   Passing clouds.                             3 mph                                 ↑                               94%                         29.98 "Hg                               NaN
25                           8:30 pm                               NaN                             52 °F                   Passing clouds.                             7 mph                                 ↑                               88%                         29.98 "Hg                               NaN
26                           9:00 pm                               NaN                             52 °F                   Passing clouds.                             5 mph                                 ↑                               82%                         29.98 "Hg                               NaN
27                           9:30 pm                               NaN                             50 °F                   Passing clouds.                             5 mph                                 ↑                               88%                         29.98 "Hg                               NaN
28                          10:00 pm                               NaN                             48 °F       Light rain. Passing clouds.                             1 mph                                 ↑                               94%                         29.95 "Hg                               NaN
29
```

**Additional:**

To get multiple days, we'll get he data through the ajax. We'll just iterate through those requests. We also need to do a slight manipulation of the info returned as it's not exactly in a valid json format, but appears to be consistent, so shouldn't be an issue.

Note: you'll need to change the `start_date` and `num_of_days` to get what you want. this example starts on Jan 1, 2014, and will get that day, plus the next 9 days (so 10 days total)

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json
import pandas as pd
import re
import datetime

start_date = '20140101'
num_of_days = 10

url = 'https://www.timeanddate.com/scripts/cityajax.php'
headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.131 Safari/537.36'}

datetime_object = datetime.datetime.strptime(start_date, '%Y%m%d')


results = pd.DataFrame()
for x in range(num_of_days):
    parse_time = datetime_object + datetime.timedelta(days=x)
    str_time = parse_time.strftime('%Y%m%d')
    month = parse_time.strftime('%#m')
    year = parse_time.strftime('%Y')

    payload = {
    'n': 'spain/salou',
    'mode': 'historic',
    'hd': str_time,
    'month': month,
    'year': year,
    'json': '1'}

    jsonStr = requests.get(url, headers=headers, params=payload).text
    jsonStr = jsonStr.replace('c:','"c":')
    jsonStr = jsonStr.replace('h:','"h":')
    jsonStr = jsonStr.replace('s:','"s":')

    jsonData = json.loads(jsonStr)

    for alpha in jsonData:
        row = alpha['c']

        try:
            date = BeautifulSoup(row[0]['h'], 'html.parser').find('span').text
        except:
            pass

        time = re.findall(r'\b((1[0-2]|0?[1-9]):([0-5][0-9]) ([AaPp][Mm]))', BeautifulSoup(row[0]['h'], 'html.parser').text)[0][0]
        condition = BeautifulSoup(row[3]['h'], 'html.parser').text
        temp = BeautifulSoup(row[2]['h'], 'html.parser').text.replace('\xa0', ' ')
        wspd = BeautifulSoup(row[4]['h'], 'html.parser').text
        wdir = BeautifulSoup(row[5]['h'], 'html.parser').text
        wdesc = BeautifulSoup(row[5]['h'], 'html.parser').find('span')['title']
        humd = BeautifulSoup(row[6]['h'], 'html.parser').text
        barm = BeautifulSoup(row[7]['h'], 'html.parser').text
        vis = BeautifulSoup(row[8]['h'], 'html.parser').text.replace('\xa0', ' ')

        temp_df = pd.DataFrame([[date, time, temp, condition, wspd, wdir, wdesc, humd, barm, vis]], columns = ['Date', 'Time', 'Temp', 'Weather', 'Wind Speed', 'Wind Direction', 'Wind Description', 'Humidity', 'Barometer', 'Visibility'])

        print ('Processed: %s %s' %(date, time))
        results = results.append(temp_df).reset_index(drop=True)
```

**Output:**

```
print (results)
            Date      Time   Temp  ... Humidity  Barometer Visibility
0     Wed, Jan 1   7:00 am  39 °F  ...      93%  30.07 "Hg      10 mi
1     Wed, Jan 1   7:30 am  41 °F  ...      87%  30.07 "Hg      10 mi
2     Wed, Jan 1   8:00 am  41 °F  ...      87%  30.07 "Hg        N/A
3     Wed, Jan 1   8:30 am  43 °F  ...      81%  30.07 "Hg        N/A
4     Wed, Jan 1   9:00 am  43 °F  ...      87%  30.07 "Hg        N/A
5     Wed, Jan 1   9:30 am  46 °F  ...      76%  30.07 "Hg        N/A
6     Wed, Jan 1  10:00 am  48 °F  ...      76%  30.09 "Hg        N/A
7     Wed, Jan 1  10:30 am  54 °F  ...      67%  30.09 "Hg        N/A
8     Wed, Jan 1  11:00 am  55 °F  ...      63%  30.09 "Hg        N/A
9     Wed, Jan 1  11:30 am  55 °F  ...      63%  30.09 "Hg        N/A
10    Wed, Jan 1  12:00 pm  57 °F  ...      63%  30.07 "Hg        N/A
11    Wed, Jan 1  12:30 pm  57 °F  ...      67%  30.07 "Hg        N/A
12    Wed, Jan 1   1:00 pm  59 °F  ...      68%  30.04 "Hg        N/A
13    Wed, Jan 1   2:00 pm  59 °F  ...      68%  30.01 "Hg        N/A
14    Wed, Jan 1   2:30 pm  59 °F  ...      68%  30.01 "Hg        N/A
15    Wed, Jan 1   3:00 pm  57 °F  ...      67%  30.01 "Hg        N/A
16    Wed, Jan 1   3:30 pm  57 °F  ...      67%  29.98 "Hg        N/A
17    Wed, Jan 1   4:00 pm  57 °F  ...      72%  30.01 "Hg        N/A
18    Wed, Jan 1   4:30 pm  55 °F  ...      77%  30.01 "Hg        N/A
19    Wed, Jan 1   5:00 pm  55 °F  ...      77%  29.98 "Hg        N/A
20    Wed, Jan 1   5:30 pm  54 °F  ...      82%  30.01 "Hg        N/A
21    Wed, Jan 1   6:00 pm  52 °F  ...      88%  29.98 "Hg        N/A
22    Wed, Jan 1   6:30 pm  52 °F  ...      88%  29.98 "Hg        N/A
23    Wed, Jan 1   7:30 pm  50 °F  ...      94%  29.98 "Hg        N/A
24    Wed, Jan 1   8:00 pm  50 °F  ...      94%  29.98 "Hg        N/A
25    Wed, Jan 1   8:30 pm  52 °F  ...      88%  29.98 "Hg        N/A
26    Wed, Jan 1   9:00 pm  52 °F  ...      82%  29.98 "Hg        N/A
27    Wed, Jan 1   9:30 pm  50 °F  ...      88%  29.98 "Hg        N/A
28    Wed, Jan 1  10:00 pm  48 °F  ...      94%  29.95 "Hg        N/A
29    Thu, Jan 2   7:00 am  43 °F  ...     100%  29.89 "Hg        N/A
..           ...       ...    ...  ...      ...        ...        ...
307  Sat, Jan 11   7:30 am  52 °F  ...      82%  30.07 "Hg        N/A
308  Sat, Jan 11   8:00 am  52 °F  ...      82%  30.07 "Hg        N/A
309  Sat, Jan 11   8:30 am  54 °F  ...      82%  30.07 "Hg        N/A
310  Sat, Jan 11   9:00 am  54 °F  ...      77%  30.09 "Hg        N/A
311  Sat, Jan 11   9:30 am  54 °F  ...      82%  30.09 "Hg        N/A
312  Sat, Jan 11  10:00 am  54 °F  ...      82%  30.12 "Hg       4 mi
313  Sat, Jan 11  10:30 am  54 °F  ...      82%  30.12 "Hg       4 mi
314  Sat, Jan 11  11:00 am  54 °F  ...      82%  30.12 "Hg       4 mi
315  Sat, Jan 11  11:30 am  55 °F  ...      77%  30.12 "Hg       4 mi
316  Sat, Jan 11  12:00 pm  57 °F  ...      72%  30.12 "Hg       4 mi
317  Sat, Jan 11  12:30 pm  57 °F  ...      72%  30.12 "Hg        N/A
318  Sat, Jan 11   1:00 pm  57 °F  ...      72%  30.09 "Hg        N/A
319  Sat, Jan 11   1:30 pm  57 °F  ...      72%  30.09 "Hg        N/A
320  Sat, Jan 11   2:00 pm  57 °F  ...      72%  30.09 "Hg        N/A
321  Sat, Jan 11   2:30 pm  59 °F  ...      72%  30.09 "Hg        N/A
322  Sat, Jan 11   3:00 pm  59 °F  ...      72%  30.07 "Hg        N/A
323  Sat, Jan 11   3:30 pm  59 °F  ...      72%  30.09 "Hg        N/A
324  Sat, Jan 11   4:00 pm  57 °F  ...      77%  30.09 "Hg        N/A
325  Sat, Jan 11   4:30 pm  57 °F  ...      77%  30.09 "Hg        N/A
326  Sat, Jan 11   5:00 pm  55 °F  ...      88%  30.09 "Hg        N/A
327  Sat, Jan 11   5:30 pm  55 °F  ...      88%  30.09 "Hg       6 mi
328  Sat, Jan 11   6:00 pm  55 °F  ...      88%  30.12 "Hg       3 mi
329  Sat, Jan 11   6:30 pm  55 °F  ...      94%  30.12 "Hg       3 mi
330  Sat, Jan 11   7:00 pm  55 °F  ...      94%  30.12 "Hg       4 mi
331  Sat, Jan 11   7:30 pm  54 °F  ...     100%  30.12 "Hg       4 mi
332  Sat, Jan 11   8:00 pm  54 °F  ...     100%  30.15 "Hg       6 mi
333  Sat, Jan 11   8:30 pm  54 °F  ...     100%  30.15 "Hg       6 mi
334  Sat, Jan 11   9:00 pm  54 °F  ...     100%  30.15 "Hg       6 mi
335  Sat, Jan 11   9:30 pm  54 °F  ...      94%  30.15 "Hg       6 mi
336  Sat, Jan 11  10:00 pm  54 °F  ...      94%  30.15 "Hg       6 mi

[337 rows x 10 columns]
```

Comment: Thank you, this is an alternative solution that I can use.

Comment: One more problem with this solution; I need to get daily weather, I mean these table only has 1 day weather information. How to obtain all of the days in this month?

Comment: @GulsahAyhan, Then we'll need to find another way. Check my solution again for the edit.

Comment: Thank you so much, great solution!